# Connection among Flask + Python, PostgreSQL + SQLAlchemy, and Android Application

Tags: android, python, postgresql

I have been considering to create a collaboration app in android for students. The app should encourage students to share their ideas and answers to questions. To do this, I know I have to program it using Android Studio. But, how do I let the users sign up with their credentials and then pass the information to my database. A friend told me to use flask with Python as server language and PostgreSQL + SQLAlchemy as the server database. So, how do I link them with my Android Application? And, do I need to install PostgreSQL and SQLAlchemy on a Linux machine to act as a server database and manage them? What's the general process?